# Unable to find method ''void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompilerOptions

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I'm unable to run the app because of this error:

```
Unable to find method ''void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompilerOptions, org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutor, org.gradle.api.model.ObjectFactory)''
'void org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.<init>(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmCompilerOptions, org.gradle.workers.WorkerExecutor, org.gradle.api.model.ObjectFactory)'
```

Here're my build.gradle files

## **build.gradle(:app)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.8.0-1.0.8"
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.mediastoredao_23jan'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mediastoredao_23jan"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    implementation ('com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1')

    def room_version = "2.5.0"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    // To use Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // lifecycle
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
}

// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

## **build.gradle Module**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}
```

## **Additional Info**

`Sync Project with Gradle Files` can run without issue, but when running the app will encounter the mentioned error.

**I've tried all of the provided solutions and hit the `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`... option.**

[Build Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5gbS.png)
The image shows the Build Output. This is Android Studio IDE 2022.1, coded in Kotlin

Comment: Unless I missed it-- what version of gradle?  (from gradle-wrapper.properties)

Comment: @fattire I think should be **version 7.5** based on `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip` from gradle-wrapper.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Updating the kotlin plugin version should help:

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false
```

1.7.21 can be updated to 1.8.0 as of this answer.